# Deploy frontend app from Azure Devops to Azure AppService

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I got Azure Devops with connection to Azure cloud.

I got **frontend repo created with React app**. Locally app works on `localhost:3000` and to run it I use the commands below:-

```bash
npm install
npm run build
npm start
```

I created pipeline that build app and then release it to **AppService**.  AppService is based on `Linux OS` with `Runtime Stack node`.  Artifacts to deploy are content from `"build"` catalog After deploy I received this error:-

```js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path //package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '//package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

What is wrong?"`build folder doesn't have package.json"` which is located one level above in catalog but I saw that I should build folder before deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808454/how-to-solve-npm-error-code-254-in-azure-devops) by Walter to resolve the error.

Make sure the node version you are selecting while running your yaml script matches the Node version of your Web app.

***My yaml script to deploy react sampleapp:-***

> ````yaml
> trigger:
> - master
>
> variables:
>
>     azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
>
>   # Web app name   webAppName: 'xxxxwebapp655'
>
>   # Environment name   environmentName: 'xxxxwebapp655'
>
>   # Agent VM image name   vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
>
> stages:
> - stage: Build   displayName: Build stage   jobs:
>   - job: Build
>     displayName: Build
>     pool:
>       vmImage: $(vmImageName)
>
>     steps:
>     - task: ArchiveFiles@2
>       displayName: 'Archive files'
>       inputs:
>         rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
>         includeRootFolder: false
>         archiveType: zip
>         archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
>         replaceExistingArchive: true
>
>     - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
>       artifact: drop
>
> - stage: Deploy   displayName: Deploy stage   dependsOn: Build   condition: succeeded()   jobs:
>   - deployment: Deploy
>     displayName: Deploy
>     environment: $(environmentName)
>     pool:
>       vmImage: $(vmImageName)
>     strategy:
>       runOnce:
>         deploy:
>           steps:
>           - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
>             displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: siliconwebapp655'
>             inputs:
>               azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
>               appType: webAppLinux
>               WebAppName: $(webAppName)
>               packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
>               RuntimeStack: 'NODE|18.10'
>               StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
>               ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
>               InlineScript: |
>                 npm install
>                 npm run build --if-present
>                  ```
> ````

**My Azure react repository:-**

[image]

***Also, refer my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76518801/azure-pipelines-code-keeps-going-under-wwwroot-s-instead-of-wwwroot/76521119#76521119) to deploy react app with Azure devops in your Azure web app***

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do npm start, just go into configurations in your azure app service and put this "pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon" command ->
also dist is that folder where your build is, you can modify this command as you want